# Unable to find the source of a rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to setup an apache server with a somewhat complex htaccess rules. I have found various solutions for individual rules, however, when I try to put the whole picture together I lack experience with htaccess to make it work and I experience some weird rewrites.

Rules:

1. The root contains `index.php` which launches a single page UI app. That means that URLs should be rewritten to `/index.php`
2. There are a few folders which should be exempt from Rule #1, e. g. if `/admin` is accessed, `/admin/index.php` should be shown, not /index.php.
3. Rule #2 also applies to all files on the server (so that the UI app can load resources like js/css/etc.)
4. All `http://*` requests should be redirected to `https://*`

Some possibly relevant details:

- The server has a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate installed. The "redirect from http" was enabled during installation, I figured it might've created some weird rewrite rules, so I navigated to `etc/apache2/sites-available/lamp-server.conf` and commented out these three lines

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =[DOMAIN]
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Here's the relevant part of `/.htaccess`. There are no other rewrites/redirects in this file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp|admin|phpmyadmin)(/.*)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

When I clear the cache in browsers, it seems to work correctly for a while. But when I open the SPA part of the server (i. e., the first RewriteRule is triggered), the browser caches some sort of rewrite and then `/admin` also starts pointing to the SPA, unless I do a `Ctrl+F5` each time.

I tried executing GET requests via Fiddler 4, everything seems to be working correctly there. Tried these scenarios:

- HTTP root - got a 302 redirect.
- HTTPS root - 200 OK.
- `/search` SPA page - got 200 OK with rendered `/index.php` as response.
- `/admin` page outside of SPA - got 200 OK with rendered `/admin/index.php` as response.

During the development of the htaccess rules there might've been a time when a 301 redirect was executed, which is now messing with my browser cache. However, then it's weird that even if I install a new fresh browser, it gets affected by the issue. Even if I try to access it from my mobile (which I never did before, so there's nothing cached), the same issue happens.

Comment: 1. If you have access to apache `.conf` files, [don't use .htaccess at all](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when)

Comment: 2. Turn on [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) logging

Comment: 3. If ctrl+f5 resolves the issue, there is probably some client side caching involved, take a look at developers console at the moment when page is not loading as you expect